# Scraping plain HTML-Content with durable connection

Tags: python, html, screen-scraping

first of all, I would like to say that I am only a hobby programmer and have absolute amateur status.

I have a mobotix camera that generates alarms when moving. With a specific URL, I can query the alarm status. If I open the URL with the browser, I get a live status in form of plain text. When the camera detects movement, an entry is written. If nothing happens for a long time, some blank lines are created.
The thing ist, that the request never ends. As you can see in the picture, there is just the firefox typical point for loading, instead of a favicon.

I tried to get the data from the website with python. But as the request never ends, it won't work...

I tried a little bit with simple "request.get" and find some examples with scrapy or beautifulsoup. But it is very very hard for me to learn these thing.
Therefore i would like to ask you guys, which is it worse to have a look or maybe you can give me a little push in the right direction.

I tried to use a simple timeout im the request, but that throws me some errors and it isn't the point of the matter, since I am trying to create a permanent/standing connection to the camera.
Then i would like to filter the number of the alarmcounter and do some new actions with this.

Sorry for my bad english. Hope you can help me.

```
import requests

url='http://192.168.0.242/control/event.jpg?output=alarmupdate&filter=AS'
user='admin'
pwd='pwd'

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.auth = (user, pwd)

r = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd), verify=False)

if r.status_code == 200:
    print('Success!')
elif r.status_code != 200:
    print('Error.')

print (r)
```

**Browser image**
[image: Browser image]

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to understand is which is your parent website.
Example: https://www.google.com/search?q& ..... is google search website also https://www.google.com/ is also a google search webpage. So first get your base website.
Then you need to try below code in python 3.x and check what does your webpage respond.

```
import requests
url = "http://www.yourwebpage.com"
print(requests.get(url))
```

Now if you receive an http 200 or 403 ( then you need to pass your credentials ) post that you are good to go. If you face any other http code, then let me know we will tackle it accordingly. Also based on that we will do a web **scrape** using BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. A comment doesn't allow me to use more letters. So I will answer:

Edit: OK...Sorry I need to learn about this forum. I should edit my first post I think and just comment...right? Sorry for that...

Thanks for your answer.
I get the HTTP Code 200. Thats not my problem. Later the cameras should be reached by the same domain on differents ports.

Here is my code till yet:

```
import requests
import time

url_alarm='http://192.168.0.246/output_emz.xml?A10A'
domain='http://192.168.0.242'
#url='/control/event.jpg?output=alarmupdate&filter=AS'
url='/control/event.jpg'
ports=['80', '8080']
user='admin'
pwd='pwd'

def Alarm():
    requests.get(url_alarm)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    requests.get(url_alarm)

def connection():
    for x in ports:
        completeurl = domain+':'+x+url
        try:
            r = requests.get(completeurl, auth=(user, pwd), verify=False)
    
            if r.status_code == 200:
                print ('Reached ' + domain + ' at Port ' + x)
                print('Sending Alarm...')
                Alarm()
                print('Alarm successfully sent \n')
            elif r.status_code != 200:
                print('Error when trying to reach ' + domain + ' at Port ' + x)
                print('Trying just to reach the domain...')
                r = requests.get(domain, auth=(user, pwd), verify=False)
                if r.status_code == 200:
                    print('This would work...')
                elif r.status_code != 200:
                    print('This also did not work. Trying next cam...')

        except:
            print('Connection to camera failed at '+completeurl)

###__________CODE__________###

connection()
```

This puts me out:

```
Reached http://192.168.0.242 at Port 80
Sending Alarm...
Alarm successfully sent

Error when trying to reach http://192.168.0.242 at Port 8080
Trying just to reach the domain...
This would work...
```

But as soon as I try to add the "?output=alarmupdate&filter=AS" the request will never end and the code never runs through...